# PDF file open but cannot load Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I'm new with create file (php laravel) and I have a problem with pdf load (Failed to load the PDF document in the browser). When I decode my base64 code in my Controller and make a pdf file with it, the pdf result code is unfamiliar.

[image: Code sublime texte 3 pdf file decode base64]

I think this is where the problem come from. This is the code to create and load the pdf file.

```
public function fileload(Request $request) {
    $name = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($request->pdf, 0, strpos($request->pdf, ';')))[1])[1];
    $data = base64_decode($request->pdf);
    $file_create = file_put_contents('files/projects/'.$name,$data);

    $file = public_path()."/files/projects/".$name;
    return response()->download($file,$name);
}
```

Vue.js(script) code where pdf in base64 is set

```
data(){
    return{
        form: new Form({
              file:'',
              filetype:'',
              pdf:'',
            })
        }
    },

methods: {
    onInputChange(e){
      let file = e.target.files[0];
      let reader = new FileReader();

      if(file['size'] < 211177555){
          reader.onloadend = (file) => {
            //console.log('RESULT',reader.result)
            this.form.file = e.target.files;
            this.form.pdf = reader.result;
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       }else{
         this.$toastr.e('Your file exceeds 2MB.');
       }
    },
```

Vuejs (template)

```
<form @submit.prevent="addFile(form.file)">
  <input type="file" id="file"  @change="onInputChange">
  <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

The output of this.form.pdf is a base64 I checked.

```
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJcfsj6IKMzAgMCBvYmoKPDwvTGVuZ3RoIDMxIDAgUi9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlPj4Kc3RyZWFtCnic7X3dkyW3be/7/BVT9yVOVfa4+U0mTzeJ45uUXXFspZKHvNgrS3K8K9mSJcf56y9+ALqbPY2ew9N7ZmVZm1SiBaabDYIAiC/y/P....
```

Comment: What is `$request->pdf` and why do you think it is encoded in base64?

Comment: It seems really weird that you expect  `$request->pdf` to contain `/`, `:` and `;` , but then throw it at a `base64_decode()` that doen't understand any of those symbols as input.

Comment: I return $request->pdf and yes its encoded in base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me `$request->pdf` is not base64, but rather a [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), which may use Base64 in it's composition but is not Base64 and will not be parsed properly by `base64_decode()`.

What gives it away is that not only you're looking for symbols like `:` and `;` in the data, but apparently you are finding them. Base64 does not contain those symbols.

`$request->pdf` is probably `data:application/pdf;base64,FileSerializedInBase64`.

This is not base64! Only the last part is.

If you throw this as is to `base64_decode()` to parse it will output garbage, which is exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks your Sir it worrk perfetly ! I only needed the FileSerializedInBase64.